# Calculate cardinal number of given A set

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, cardinals

Let $x \in \mathbb R$.

Let $\text A x = \{ y \in \mathbb R : |x-y| \in \mathbb Z \}$

Find $| \text A x |$.

Now I understand I need to use a bijective function, to send $\text  A x$ to a known caridnal number group like $\mathbb N$ which is $\aleph_0$.

is that the correct approach? a bit stuck.

Comment: Basically for a fixed $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ and a fixed $z \in \mathbb Z$, how many reals $y$ there are such that $|x_0 - y| = z$ ? Find it and multiply it for the number of elements of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA there is only one y, and the number of Z elements is infinite no?

Comment: No, there are two $y$. And yes, the cardinality of $\mathbb Z$ is *infinite*, but is it $\aleph_0$ or greater ?

Comment: I knew it, because its in absolute value - forgot about that. its ℵ0 which means it equals as the natural numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x=[x]+{x},y=[y]+{y}.  |x-y| is in Z iff {x}={y}.
Therefore elements of S=Ax are uniquely determined by [y]. Thus |S|=Z=N

Comment: cant understand the first sentence from x to the absloute value

Comment: [x] is the integer part of x,{x} denotes its fractional part

Comment: so no need to use functions to prove?

Comment: |S|=Z follows from the natural map x->[x] .Will u be able to show that |Z|=|N|?

Comment: yes from there its easier